# freezing when an external display is connected

Tags: display, macbook

I'm using ubuntu(16.04) in my macbook(cpu:core 2 duo, graphic:NVIDIA GeForce 9400M).
When I connected an external display via hdmi-minidisplay cable, my macbook built-in display began to flash and freeze(no response for click).
Why this happens? How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this promblem by myself.
I changed GeForce 9400M driver to Nvidia binary driver from x server by GUI(Additional Drivers). 
It worked.